# Where to test links in cucumber features?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, bdd, code-organization, scenarios

Assume that I arranged my cucumber features in files like that:

```
features/
├── add_project.feature
├── list_projects.feature
```

In my application on the page where I can list all projects I also have a link that points to the page where I can create a new project. I want to test that link with the following scenario:

```
Scenario: Link to create page is visible
    Given I am logged in as a staff member
    When I go to the projects page
    Then I should see a link to the create a project page
```

Now my dilemma: Where do I put this scenario?

- Put the scenario into `list_projects.feature`.

  - **+** The link is on the list projects page
  - **-** When I am interested in the list projects feature I don't want to read about how I am  adding projects
- Put the scenario into `add_projects.feature`.

  - **+** When I read the description of this feature I am also interested how users are going to get to that feature
  - **+** If I have multiple links to that functionality they all are gathered in one place
  - **-** The basic 1-on-1 mapping of feature and controller is broken, to me it feels that this is intruding another test's responsibility
- Put the scenario somewhere else altogether.

  - I have no idea where :-)

I am sure people have faced this problem before and I want to establish a guideline for the application, right now both styles can be found which makes it harder to maintain. Any input how you did it and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would include that behaviour in the add_projects.feature

Although Cucumber's built-in generators seem to encourage the mapping of one feature per controller, this often isn't the best way to arrange things so don't worry about breaking that convention.